# Binance RSI Chart to Python

Tags: python, webhooks, cryptocurrency, binance

I've recently gotten into cryptocurrency. When looking at the charts, I find myself looking at the RSI Chart the most. I was wondering if there was a way I could have a Python script that prints out the RSI value for a crypto (every 15 seconds or so), such as ETH. I've watched videos where it calculates it itself. However, I want a chart such as this one on Binance:
[image]
I don't actually want the chart, I just want the value. I'm unsure of how this is done by Binance, and I'm unsure of how to recreate this. If anyone has done anything like this in the past, please share!